# Create resource dependencies in MS project 2010

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010, resources, dependencies, constraints

e.g. I have a task that has to be fulfilled by two persons, but person B cannot start before person A has finished his part of the task. How do I scedule this in MS project 2010 without having to split the task in subtasks?

So, how do I enter resource dependencies/constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless this is supported in Project Server, of which I have no experience, you cannot do this in MS-Project. It simply does not include the concept of resource dependencies within a task.

In any case, despite the fact you say you do not want to split the task, the fact that it has two parts fulfilled by two separate resources with a strict linear order, means that the overall task *does* consist of two subtasks. If that is the reality then modelling it any other way in MS-Project does not make sense.

I don't know whether it is any more palatable to you, but if I were doing this I would create an umbrella task and indent one level for the two sub-tasks which you can then order using a Finish-to-Start constraint. Then just use the umbrella task as if it were one task, i.e. it have its own constraints and scheduling (to a certain extent), it just happens to be made up two separate tasks internally.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter when resources work on tasks in the Task Usage view or in the Task form with the Schedule format applied.  However, as Marv notes, there is not a way to create a resource dependency -only task dependencies.